# adding json object name in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, json, backbone.js

created an web api that outputs json, trying to use it with backbone.js pagination plugin to ouput the results to the backbone.js infinite-paging plugin

this is my outputed json

```
    [{"id":1,"title":"test1""desc":"book1"},
    {"id":2,"title":"test2","desc":"book2"},
    {"id":3,"title":"test3", "desc":"book3"},
    {"id":4,"title":"test4","desc":"book4"},
    {"id":5,"title":"test5","desc":"book5"},
    {"id":6,"title":"test6","desc":"book6"}]
```

but i need to have the name of object included as the backbone.js paginator requires to return the response object. think im almost there but cant seem to get it to show or work out how i add the object name to it ?

```
 {"object name:"[{"id":1,"title":"test1","desc":"book1"},            {"id":2,"title":"test2","desc":"book2"},
{"id":3,"title":"test3","desc":"book3"},
{"id":4,"title":"test4","desc":"book4"},
{"id":5,"title":"test5","desc":"book5"},
{"id":6,"title":"test6","desc":"book6"}]}

public class latestnewsController : EntitySetController<news, int>
{
    onlinepressEntities _context = new onlinepressEntities();


    latestnewsController()
    {
        _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    [Queryable]
    public override IQueryable<news> Get()
    {
        return _context.news;

    }

    protected override news GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        return _context.news.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == key);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _context.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: I've run into a similar issue. In my case I need it with the object/model name in order for swagger ui to generate proper documentation. I'll update this if I find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive "news" on the client add it as a property of an existing object.

```
var news = getNews();
var thing = { "object name" : news };
backbone(thing);
```